# Avoid carriage returns in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, width

I have a simple TextView and I want it to automatically define the font size to prevent returns.
is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that when i'll do textView.setText("udini\nblabla"), i'll see only "udiniblabla"?

Comment: No i need to show the time (ex: 10:30:10) full large with no returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a component I've used in the past:

[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

This text view will resize the font size by size of the text in it. Try it